# cloud-init - Hostname strange behavior

Tags: cloud-init

I am using the cloud-Assembly to create a VM with following settings:

```
hostname:redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest
domain: test.local
```

Cloud Assembly code below:

```
  cloudConfig: |
    #cloud-config
    preserve_hostname: false
    prefer_fqdn_over_hostname: false
    hostname: '${input.hostname}'
    fqdn: '${input.hostname}.${input.domain}'
```

What I am getting is the following:

```
redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest log]# hostname
redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest.test.local
```

cat /var/lib/cloud/data/set-hostname

```
{
 "fqdn": "redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest.test.local",
 "hostname": "redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest"
}
```

cat /var/lib/cloud/data/previous-hostname

```
redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest.test.local[root@redhat-kouvas-1500-localtest log]#
```

Do you know why the cloud-init has this strange behavior??

================================================================================

### Copied the following from cloud-init documentation

[cloud-init-documentation link](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html?highlight=set_hostname#module-cloudinit.config.cc_set_hostname)

```
Internal name: cc_set_hostname

Module frequency: once-per-instance

Supported distros: all

Config schema:
preserve_hostname: (boolean) If true, the hostname will not be changed. Default: false.

hostname: (string) The hostname to set.

fqdn: (string) The fully qualified domain name to set.

prefer_fqdn_over_hostname: (boolean) If true, the fqdn will be used if it is set. If false, the hostname will be used. If unset, the result is distro-dependent.

Examples:

preserve_hostname: true
# --- Example2 ---
hostname: myhost
fqdn: myhost.example.com
prefer_fqdn_over_hostname: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by changing the preserve_hostname: True